# Поиск кода функции хука WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Если ленивый - **читай сразу последний абзац**!

Файл **content-product.php**, строка **do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item' );** выводит кнопку "В корзину", при нажатии товар добавляется в корзину, пользователь остается на странице магазина.

Нужно заменить эту кнопку на кнопку "Посмотреть" (на сайте функционал корзины не используется, сайт не интернет-магазин, а интернет-каталог оффлайн-магазина) так, чтобы при нажатии пользователя отправляло на страницу товара , под которым эта кнопка находится(как при нажатии на изображение товара).

Чтобы вы понимали о чем речь: [ссылка на сам сайт](http://w98117w7.beget.tech/product-category/monuments/), не обессудьте ;-)

Я думал что **do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item' );** возвращает **echo "...html..."** и попытался найти функцию которая этот код генерирует, но я не понимаю как искать функцию которая вызывается с помощью хука. *Помогите мне с поиском пожалуйста)*

Comment: Если ленивый - иди сразу к фрилансерам. Вежливей надо быть. Зачем переписывать код хука, если можно просто вставить ссылку на пост вместо него?

Comment: Я не хотел никого оскорбить, простите если вас это задело, стоило написать по другому.
Я понимаю что можно просто обойтись ссылкой, но я не понимаю как это сделать, веть если я просто напишу что-то в виде <a href="http://example.com"></a> то под каждым товаром будет одна и таже ссылка, а не разные, динамично сгенерированные под каждый товар со ссылкой на него.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как искать функцию которая вызывается с помощью хука - это хороший вопрос. Такие действия приходится выполнять по несколько раз на дню.

Понятно, что искать можно только по файлам исходных текстов. То есть, как минимум, должна быть полная локальная копия сайта. Учитывая, что WordPress - это примерно полмиллиона строк, а WooCommerce - 300 тысяч строк, поиск по подпапкам стандартными средствами (например, Total Commander) - это очень долго. Нужно индексирование.

Современные IDE (например, phpStorm) индексируют исходные тексты проекта, и поиск по всему проекту осуществляется практически мгновенно, по мере ввода символов в строке поиска.

В вашем случае: вызываем окно глобального поиска в phpStorm (ctrl+shift+f), вводим `'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item'`. Моментально получаем все упоминания в проекте:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Видим, что в самом WooCommerce есть файл `wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/wc-template-hooks.php`, в котором присутствует строка (подсвечена на картинке)

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10 );
```

Кликаем на строку, открывается файл. Подводим указатель мыши к `woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart`, удерживая ctrl.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Видим, что IDE вывела краткое описание функции `woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart` и её параметров. Кликаем на `woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart`, удерживая ctrl.

И IDE открывает тот участок исходного текста, где объявлена `woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart`, причём неважно, в каком файле эта находится.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Таким образом, процесс поиска занимает 5 секунд, которые в основном уходят на чтение первой выдачи по ctrl+shift+f.

Answer (score 0):

Решил с помощью get_permalink()! Спасибо обидевшемуся на меня комментатору.

Comment: Я не обиделся :) Вот-вот, нужно было просто поставить ссылку, зачем хук?